# How to close a external application with java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Knowing which java.exe process to kill on a windows machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62418/knowing-which-java-exe-process-to-kill-on-a-windows-machine)
>   [How to kill a process in Java, given a specific PID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633678/how-to-kill-a-process-in-java-given-a-specific-pid)

I am trying to find out how to close a particular external exe namely cwserv5.exe. I have succeeded in starting a new external exe and closing it .But not an existing process. Can you help? Below is what I was tinkering with but really lost to be honest

```
package com.TestCase;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ReStartEXE {

    static Process pr; 

    public static void open() {

        //ProcessBuilder

         try {
             Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
             //Process pr = rt.exec("cmd /c dir");
              pr = rt.exec("C:\\APPLEGREEN\\webserv\\cwserv5rost.exe");         

             Thread.sleep(10000);
             //pr.wait(10000);
            //pr.waitFor();

             BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

            // String line=null;

             /*while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
                 System.out.println(line);
             }*/

             //int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
             //pr.destroy();
           // Process.kill(pr);
            // Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM cwserv5rost.exe");

             //System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);

         } catch(Exception e) {
             System.out.println(e.toString());
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }


    public static void Close() {

        pr.destroy();

    }

}
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81902/how-to-find-and-kill-running-win-processes-from-within-java

Answer (score 7):

You can do this by executing a process to close the process that you want to close.

In your comments I can see `taskkill`, which means that you're probably using Windows.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

rt.exec("taskkill /F /IM cwserv5.exe");
```

This will force the process with image name `cwserv5.exe` to end.

If you don't want to force it to end, don't use the `/f` tag.

For more information on `taskkill`, go to `cmd` (command prompt) and type `taskkill /?`.

Comment: Thanks all for you great help

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
    Process proc = rt.exec("taskkill /F /IM cwserv5.exe");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null){
         //do something
     }
    input.close();
    code = proc.exitValue();
    if(code==0){
        //success
    }
    else{
        //failure
    }
```

Comment: Wait a sec. He wants to close `cwserv5.exe`.

Comment: yes, thats what this code will do, it is same as your code also giving the exitValue