# Find and kill a specific Java process from another Java App

Tags: java, windows, taskmanager

I have several java processes running on a windows machine. I have a Java process which is supposed to monitor the other processes and periodically kill or restart new ones.

If I have a java process running com.foo.Main1 and one running com.foo.Main2 - how can my monitoring process find and kill just the Main2 process?

Update: I have some code that can execute a command line tasklist.exe and parse it, but no matter what I do, I only see the java.exe process, not which class is executing

Update 2: I do not have the ability to install non-java programs.

Comment: See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62418/knowing-which-java-exe-process-to-kill-on-a-windows-machine) and the second answer about jps. the wmic way will probably work as well. Marking this as a duplicate...

Comment: @eis not really a duplicate since this question asks how to do it from another Java app while the other thread is all about using OS tools to do it

Comment: I ended up just using a cobbled together bunch of OS commands and a mishmash of ProcessBuilder and Runtime.exec to do it. We should close this as a dupe, as eis suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably going to be a lot simpler using OS-specific tools and using `Runtime.exec()` to run them, but I'll try and give a platform independent answer:

---

It might be possible to do this platform independently using the [Attach API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/attach/).  This comes with the JDK, so to use it just include `tools.jar` from your JDK on your program's classpath.

To get a list of virtual machines on the system, use [VirtualMachine.list()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html#list%28%29).  You can get/parse arguments from the virtual machine descriptor objects that are returned from this.

The attach API also allows you to load agents into already-running Java processes.  Since you want to kill a Java process, you can write a Java agent that simply runs [System.exit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) (or if you *really* want it dead use [Runtime.halt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#halt%28int%29) instead) when the agent loads.

Once you identify the one you want to kill, [attach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html#attach%28com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachineDescriptor%29) to it and load the killer agent (the agent has to be built as a JAR file, accessible to the Java process it needs to be loaded into).  Shortly after the agent is attached that process should die.

These links might help also:

[An Oracle blog on the attach API](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_attach_api)

[Package documentation for java.lang.instrument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) (has detailed instructions on how to build an agent JAR)

Comment: Thanks. I did end up using a bunch of commands like WMIC and TASKKILL, but this was super neat - I didn't know you could get info on other running VM's. +1 for teaching me something new.

Comment: After struggling with the commands not always working (depending on admin/guest settings and other issues) I did end up using the Attach API. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is specific to Windows.
I was facing the same issue where I have to kill the specific java program using taskkill. When I run the java program, tasklist was showing the same program with Image name set as java.exe. But killing it using taskkill /F java.exe will stop all other java applications other than intended one which is not required.

So I run the same java program using:

start "MyProgramName" java java-program..

Here start command will open a new window and run the java program with window's title set to MyProgramName.

Now to kil this java-program use the following taskkill command:

taskkill /fi "MyProgramName"

Your Java program will be killed only. Rest will be unaffected.

Comment: I like this answer, but it doesn't seem as though you can set the "alias" when using the Java ProcessBuilder.