# Find out what JRE is used to run app in Windows with multiple JREs installed

Tags: java, windows

I have multiple JREs installed (6,7,8 both 32 and 64 bit). The way I have set things up is that I have the set up a number of `JAVA_x_HOME` paths and then reference `JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_x_HOME%` depending on wich version I want to use. However im not sure every application uses `JAVA_HOME` when deciding wich JRE to execute on.

Therfore my questions are:

Is there is a way to check wich JRE is used for running some started Java program under Windows 7?

What are the way an application can detect wich JRE to execute on?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62418/knowing-which-java-exe-process-to-kill-on-a-windows-machine. It point's you to a tool that can help you get wich java processes are running and thus the JRE used.

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.getProperty("java.version");`

It will return the jvm's version your code is running on. For example `1.8.0_25`.

With `System.getProperty("java.runtime.version");` you will get the runtime version, e.g. `1.8.0_25-b18`

Answer (score 1):

With `System.getProperty("java.home");` you can find the installation directory for JRE the VM is running.

You can also get the `"java.version"` if you prefer.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)'s the reference for other System Properties that may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the easiest way to do this is to open task manager and right click the task i want to inspect. Right click and select go to process. After this I can select Properties and then the Details tab. This will show me the version of Java used for this process.

Answer (score 0):

Go to cmd and run this command. This command will tell you java home set as on environment..

```
java -version  //for windows 

java -v // for linux
```