# Start/stop service for jenkins in not working in windows

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins. I have installed Jenkins on Apache tomcat server. I have installed few plugins and have to restart it. When I try to restart using http://localhost:8080/jenkins/safeRestart it does not work and displays message "Jenkins cannot restart itself as currently configured". I tried  to restart using windows service "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins>Jenkins.exe restart,'jenkins.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file. Can you please let me know if there are any other way to restart it.

Thanks and Regards
Swathi

Comment: I was trying to restart through cli , and I get the below error                      ERROR: Unexpected exception occurred while performing safe-restart command.
hudson.lifecycle.RestartNotSupportedException: Default Windows lifecycle does not support restart.   How to fix it??

Comment: For me, end task for any Java processes finally killed Jenkins. As restarting windows service just didn't work. If multiple java processes, then you may need something else to identify the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62418/knowing-which-java-exe-process-to-kill-on-a-windows-machine

Answer (score 1):

1-try the plugin in jenkins :

```
SafeRestart plugin
```

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SafeRestart+Plugin

2-stop your jinkins server , and run this command

```
java -jar jenkins.war restart
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to restart, `java -jar jenkins.war restart ` then start `java -jar jenkins.war` . hope helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but perhaps this helps:
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-23147?focusedCommentId=397550&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-397550

> Thanks to Tom Manning for this:
> The fix is to enable the group policy setting "Local Computer Policy->Administrative Templates->System->User Profiles->Do not forcefully >unload the users registry at user logoff".